How Can I Make WordPress Show a Login Button to Loggout Vistors When targeting Specific User Roles
I'm creating a job platform on Wordpress, and i wanted to show apply button on a single job page if the user is candidate, Employed if user is employee, and Submit similar Job if user is employer then if user is admin, subscriber or logged out it should show login to apply.
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();

      if ( Jobi_User::is_candidate($user_id)) { ?>
          <div class="jobi-button">
           <?php Jobi_Listing::display_apply_job_btn($post->ID); ?>
          </div>       

       <?php  } elseif ( method_exists('Jobi_User', 'is_employee') && Jobi_User::is_employee($user_id) ) {?>
             <div class="jobi-button"> 
              <span>Employee</span>
                  </div> 
       <?php } elseif ( Jobi_User::is_employer($user_id) ) { ?> 
            <div class="jobi-button"> 
              <span>Employer</span>
             </div>

       <?php } else { ?>
       <div class="jobi-button login"> 
               <a href="#apus_login_forgot_form" class="btn btn-apply"><?php esc_html_e('Login to Apply', 'jobi'); ?><i class="next flaticon-right-arrow"></i></a> 
               </div> 
               <div class="jobi-button register"> 
             <a target="_blank" href="/join-jobi/" class="btn btn-apply"><?php esc_html_e('Register to Apply', 'jobi'); ?><i class="next flaticon-right-arrow"></i></a> 
              </div>           
    <?php }
            
                  
}?>

With the above code, I was able to show the apply button when the user is candidate, and when the user is employee is shows Employee and if user is employer it shows employer correctly.
Then when logged in users are not candidate, employer or employee it shows login or register to apply.
But when no one is logged in, the space go blank, it doesn't show login or register to apply.
I want it to also show login or register to apply to visitors that are not logged in.

you have surrounded all your code with if is_user_logged_in then just remove this test.
